# Read each line in a text file for strings, doubles, and ints an place them in different arrays

Tags: java

this is my first question here so I hope I'm doing this right.  I have a programming project that needs to read each line of a tab delimited text file and extract a string, double values, and int values.  I'm trying to place these into separate arrays so that I can use them as parameters.  This is what I have so far(aside from my methods):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoanDriver {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] stringData = new String[9];
    Scanner strings = null;

    try 
    {
        FileReader read = new FileReader("amounts.txt");//Read text file.
        strings = new Scanner(read);

        String skip = strings.nextLine();//Skip the first line by storing it in an uncalled variable

        strings.useDelimiter("\t *");//Tab delimited


    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException error) 
    {}

    while (strings.hasNext())
        {
            String readLine = strings.next();
            stringData = readLine.split("\t");
        }
}}
```

If I try to get the [0] value, it skips all the way to the bottom of the file and returns that value, so it works to some extent, but not from the top like it should. Also, I can't incorporate arrays into it because I always get an error that String[] and String is a type mismatch.

Comment: Could you post example content of "amount.txt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using delimiter, try reading the file line by line using `Scanner.nextLine` and split each new line you read using `String.split` ("\t" as argument).

```
try {
    FileReader read = new FileReader("amounts.txt");//Read text file.
    strings = new Scanner(read);
    String skip = strings.nextLine();//Skip the first line by storing it in an uncalled variable
}
catch (FileNotFoundException error) { }

String line;
while ((line = strings.nextLine()) != null) {            
     String[] parts = line.split("\t");
     //...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work you cannot make a scanner a string? (line = strings.hasNext()) does not work.

Comment: @plasticpie: Sorry, it's actually `line = strings.nextLine()`. "you cannot make a scanner a string." Sorry I don't what you are trying to say.

Comment: I figured it out on my own, but I was able to use your information as a guide. Thank you!  Sorry I was unclear.

Comment: @plasticpie: No problem. Glad that it was helpful. But you can post your solution as answer and accept it to mark this post as solved though.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the last value in the file when you grab `stringData[0]` because you overwrite `stringData` each time you go through the while loop.  So the last value is the only one present in the array at the end.  Try this instead:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
while (strings.hasNext()) {
    values.add(strings.next());
}

stringData = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
```

Comment: Ah I understand where where I went wrong with that, thank you!